# Bouncing Ball doesn't come back pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width = 400
hight = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, hight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Engine")
dot = pygame.image.load("KreisSchwarz.png")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Set (x, y) for Dot
def updateDot(x, y):
    screen.blit(dot, (x, y))

# Display Dot at (x, y)
def update(fps=30):
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    updateDot(x, y)
    pygame.display.flip()
    return clock.tick(fps)

# Quit if User closes the window
def evHandler():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

yKoords = []
(x, y) = (300, 200)
t = 1 # time variable
a = 2 # acceleration constant
tol = 40 # tolerance
i = 0 # just some iterator

# MAIN LOOP
while running:
    evHandler()
    update()
    y += a * (t ^ 2)
    t += 1
    yKoords.append(int(y))
    i += 1

    if (y < (hight + tol)) and (y > (hight - tol)):
        y = 580
        yKoords.reverse()
        update()

        for q in range(i):
            evHandler()
            y = yKoords[q]
            update()
            if q == i - 1: # Because i didn't write the Part for the Dot coming back down
                running = False
```

This is my Code for a Ball accelerating down and then jumping back up.
My Problem is, that the code works fine until the if statement. There the Programm just displays the Ball at the last position in `yKoords` and waits until the for loop finishes. If i remove the for loop the Ball gets displayed at y=580 and stops but thats fine.

Please help i have no idea whats wrong about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a separate process loop in the main loop.

It is sufficient to invert the direction, when the ball bounce on the ground (`abs(y - hight)`) or the ball reaches the top (`t == 0`).

```py
direction = 1
while running:
    evHandler()
    update()
    y += (a * (t ^ 2)) * direction
    t += direction

    if abs(y - hight) < tol:
        y = 580
        t -= 1
        direction *= -1
    elif t == 0:
        direction *= -1
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much but what is the problem with my worse solution. I nevertheless want to understand whats causing the Ball not being displayed during the for loop so i don't make such a mistake in the future.

Comment: @Hellstormer The display is only updated if you call `pygame.display.flip()`